# Bootstrap toast doesn't hide automatically and confused why

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a web app (asp .net webforms) that I am integrating bootstrap into.  I have one page where the bootstrap toast is displayed and fades away as intended.  I have another page where the toast displays as intended, but fails to fade away.  One of the toasts that does not fade away is shown below.  I have this exact same code running on another page and it does fade out properly.  I think that the problem is something the toast is within.  Any suggestions regarding what I should look for?  TIA

```
  <div id="nextStepDeleteConfirmation" class="toast fixed-top text-white bg-primary border-0" 
                  role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-delay="3000">
    <div class="toast-body">
        <div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"> blah blah You have selected to delete an activity log record on the next update of this TA.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```